# Indefinite integral. Help

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$\int\frac{2x+3}{x^2-4}dx=\int\frac{2x+3}{(x+2)(x-2)}dx$

So...

$A=\frac{1}{4}$

$B=\frac{7}{4}$

$\frac{1}{4}\log_{10}|x+2|+\frac{7}{4}\log_{10}|x-2|+c$

The result should be: $\log_{10}|x^2-4|+\frac{3}{4}\log_{10}|\frac{x-2}{x+2}|+c$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can downvoters explain their vote ? This is a first post, it is LateX formatted and shows some work ! This is ideally what we encourage on mathSE, we should reward such questions, not downvote. Sure A,B are mysterious, but 2s of thinking and you can guess they are coefficients for partial fraction decomposition, it doesn't deserve to be punished that severely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation is correct (apart from using $\log_{10}$ instead of $\log$, with implied base $e$, or $\ln$).

Probably the book chose a different approach:
$$
\frac{2x+3}{x^2-4}=\frac{2x}{x^2-4}+\frac{3}{x^2-4}=
\frac{2x}{x^2-4}+\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{x+2}
$$
so integration gives
$$
\log\lvert x^2-4\rvert+\frac{3}{4}\log\left|\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right|+c
$$
However this is in no way “better” than your form for the antiderivative.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't go wrong. You simply didn't rewrite the result for simplification.
(B.t.w.the solution is in terms of the *natural*, not *decimal* log). Here's how it goes:
$$\frac14\ln|x+2|+\frac74\ln|x-2|=\Bigl(1-\frac34\Bigr)\ln|x+2|+=\Bigl(1+\frac34\Bigr)\ln|x-2|=\dots$$